# Print not visible in a class method - python

Tags: python

I call a method in an instantiated class to print "Hello World." The constructor prints its message in console but not the other method. I'm new to Python, can anyone explain why?

```
class Zapper:

  def __init__(self, name):
    print "My name is " + name
    Zapper.zap

  def zap():
    print "Hello World!"

zing = Zapper('Frank')
zing.zap
```

Comment: You forgot the `()` at the end of `Zapper.zap`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can find a decent introduction to Python classes at [the official python documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#class-objects).

Basically, you want `zap` to be an instance method and always call it on an instance of the class.

Here comes your corrected and extended example:

```
class Zapper:
  def __init__(self, name):
    print "My name is " + name
    self.name = name
    self.zap()

  def zap(self):
    print "Hello World, my name is still " + self.name

zing = Zapper('Frank')
zing.zap()
```

Note that we store the value of `name` in a instance variable called `self.name`. To access this variable later, you need to have a reference to the instance. That's why `zap` gets `self` as its first parameter. Now we can use `self.name` in the `zap` method too.

Internally, the dot-notation is converted as follows:

```
self.zap() => Zapper.zap(self)
zing.zap() => Zapper.zap(zing)
```

Answer (score 1):

Python requires the parenthesis around methods in order to call them. If you don't include them, you just get back the bound method object (which is useful in some circumstances). What you want is:

```
zing.zap()
```